# distributivity of club shooting forcing destroyed in the limit

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $S\subset \omega_1$ be a stationary and co-stationary set. Let $CU(S)$ be the standard forcing that shoots a club into $S$. It is a standard fact that $CU(S)$ is countably distributive, i.e. it adds no $\omega$ sequence of ordinals. 
Does there exist an iteration of proper forcings $\langle P_i, \dot{Q}_j: i\leq \omega, j<\omega\rangle$ (in full support here) such that

- at each finite stage $i<\omega$, $P_i$ is countably distributive;
- $\Vdash_{P_\omega} (CU(S))^V$ is not countably distributive.

Note that necessarily the iteration must add a real in the limit, since otherwise, $(CU(S))^V=(CU(S))^{V^{P_\omega}}$ and the preservation of the properness of $S$ imply that $(CU(S))^V$ is still countably distributive.

It is also of interest to me if instead of requiring $P_i$ to be countably distributive, I merely require that $\Vdash_{P_i} (CU(S))^V$ is countably distributive (which by the way by the reasoning above follows if $P_i$ is countably distributive). This case allows some forcing that adds reals.

Comment: Do you know any example in which a proper forcing forces $CU(S)^V$ to be non countably distributive?

Comment: The specializing forcing does and it's ccc

Comment: I mean if you view the forcing as an Omega 1-height tree

Comment: @Otto would you mind providing some more detail, when you say "The specializing forcing", what exactly are you talking about?

Comment: Conditions are finite functions $c$ with domain contained in $CU(S)$ to $\omega$ such that for $a <_{CU(S)} b$, then $c(a)\neq c(b)$. This poset is ccc (as $S$ is co-stationary).

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank you for clarifying.